# Hibernate Criteria Subqueries Join

Tags: java, hibernate, join, subquery, criteria

I am new to this, please let me know what I doing wrong. Thanks.

I been spending several hours to find solution on this but couldn't find any.

Supposed I have 2 tables like this:

```
TableOne
column1(PK)      column2(PK)     column3    column4
    A                 1             10
    A                 2             9

TableTwo
column5(PK)      column6     column7     column8
    A
```

Is there any hibernate criteria equivalent to:

```
select * from tableone t1, tableone t11,
      (select column1, count(*) as COUNT from tabletwo group by column1) t2
where t1.column1 = t11.column1
and t1.column2 = 1
and t11.column2 = 2
and t11.column3 = t2.COUNT
and t11.column1 = t2.column1;
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

No. Criteria quesries don't support subqueries in the select clause. HQL should be able to handle such a query, though.

Criteria queries are more limited and harder to use and read than HQL queries. My advice is to use them only when the query must be dynamically generated, or when multiple methods share a significant common portion of a complex query.